# Add sound to notification

Tags: android

A I create a notification

```
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("My notification!");
mBuilder.setContentText("Hello world!!!");
Uri notifiSound;
notifiSound = Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/музыка/Hi-Fi -  мы любили.mp3");
mBuilder.setSound(notifiSound);
Intent resIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resIntent, 0);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendIntent);

NotificationManager mNotifyMng = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyMng.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Log cat

```js
03-07 17:08:26.146: E/UsbDebuggingManager(949): Communication error: 
03-07 17:08:26.146: E/UsbDebuggingManager(949): java.io.IOException: Connection refused
03-07 17:08:26.146: E/UsbDebuggingManager(949):     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
03-07 17:08:26.146: E/UsbDebuggingManager(949):     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:290)
03-07 17:08:26.146: E/UsbDebuggingManager(949):     at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:130)
03-07 17:08:26.146: E/UsbDebuggingManager(949):     at com.android.server.usb.UsbDebuggingManager.listenToSocket(UsbDebuggingManager.java:75)
03-07 17:08:26.146: E/UsbDebuggingManager(949):     at com.android.server.usb.UsbDebuggingManager.run(UsbDebuggingManager.java:111)
03-07 17:08:26.146: E/UsbDebuggingManager(949):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I add sound from sdcard but nothing.
How to add android sound and sound from sdcard?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

There are few way you could achieving this

1.)

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.yoursoundfilename);

mBuilder.setSound(sound);
```

I explain you in detailly

put your mp3 file to res->raw folder. e.g. filename.mp3

```
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.yourpackagename/" + R.raw.filename);
mBuilder.setSound(sound);
```

OR

```
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.yourpackagename/raw/filename");
mBuilder.setSound(sound);
```

Do normal notification procedures

you can use default sound with your notification:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

if you want to play Custom sound from your sdcard with your notification:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/path/filename.mp3");
```